# wxPython; right click context menu in any text field can crash program with the error "m_menuDepth > 0"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, wxpython

I noticed that when right clicking a text field in a wxPython widget, if the user selects the `Insert Unicode control character` option and inserts any of those characters[image: example image]the program will throw this error;

> ```
> wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "m_menuDepth > 0" failed at ..\..\src\msw\toplevel.cpp(1545) in wxTopLevelWindowMSW::DoSendMenuOpenCloseEvent(): No open menus?
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> SystemError: <class 'wx._core.CommandEvent'> returned a result with an error set
> ```

Here's an example code which will throw the error;

```
import wx


class Program(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(0, 0)
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)

        self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel)
        self.sizer.Add(self.text_ctrl, wx.GBPosition(0, 0))

        # Needed, because there probably has to be some events which
        # can be processed for the error to show before closing the program.
        # Without this the error only appears after exiting.
        self.text_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, lambda e: print("text changed"))

        self.sizer.Layout()
        self.Show()


app = wx.App()
program = Program(parent=None)
app.MainLoop()
```

How can this error be prevented without redoing the context menu from scratch and without disabling it completely and without wrapping lots of stuff in `try-except` (really bad habit to catch `wx._core.wxAssertionError`, because they are generally fatal)?

Edit:

The bug is reproducable on:

**Operating system:** Win 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB / Win 10 Pro (tested on both)

**wxPython version & source:** 4.0.2 / 4.0.3 from pip3 (tested on both)

**Python version & source:** Python 3.6.5 stock

Comment: Looks like that functionality is being played with. It works fine on Linux with wx 4.0.3, yet with 4.0.1 the option is not there, instead it offers `Insert Emoji`. Best guess, move up to >= wx 4.0.3

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I updated my wxPython to 4.0.3 and the error persists, it's probably Windows specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug with wxPython and will be fixed in a future release.

The issue can be tracked here: https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/992